# Twilio Voice URL - Giving HTTP status code 502 when HTTPS (SSL) is implemented

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, twilio

I have configured SSL for all of my APIs ( Node.js). Have purchased certs recently from GoDaddy. And I verified using openssl command that its using TLSv1 protocol.

But when I set my Twilio number to call to my API ist throwing HTTP status code 502. It does work when I turn off SSL. So its clearly issue with Twilio calling my HTTPS API.
Error : 
An attempt to retrieve content from https://api... returned the HTTP status code 502.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: 502 is `Bad Gateway`.  That sounds like you have a reverse proxy configuration, and your reverse proxy can't connect to your nodejs server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Twilio priorities ECDHE ciphers. By default my Node server was using TLS cipher: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256. 
AES256-SHA is a CBC cipher and therefore susceptible to BEAST attacks. Do not use it.
I added list of all ciphers to include and execlue in my node server. See doc : https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

After adding below options to my node server SSL settings Twilio started communication with my https APIs.

```
    ciphers:[       "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
                    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256",
                    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
                    "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
                    "HIGH",
                    "!aNULL",
                    "!eNULL",
                    "!EXPORT",
                    "!DES",
                    "!RC4",
                    "!MD5",
                    "!PSK",
                    "!SRP",
                    "!CAMELLIA"
            ].join(':'),
    honorCipherOrder: true
```

Answer (score 0):

before, we had only these ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

we added these:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

and twilio can again connect